# I want to Down to up Animate new page when I tap FAB flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to Down to up animate new page when I tap FAB and close Page when I tap again FAB.
FAB button has "add icon" when tap it change angle by 45 degree.

[FAB in Normal Position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYBng.jpg)

[FAB in Active Position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siUqw.jpg)

[here is the body where I want to display that screen and bottomnavigationbar will stay where it is right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twTn0.jpg)

Comment: you want to tap on FAB then change FAB icon?

Comment: no i achieved that but i want to display a screen when it's clicked and close screen when clicked again

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what you want, [page-route-animation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/animation/page-route-animation):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: Page1(),
    ),
  );
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(_createRoute());
          },
          child: const Text('Go!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Route _createRoute() {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => const Page2(),
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      const begin = Offset(0.0, 1.0);
      const end = Offset.zero;
      const curve = Curves.ease;

      var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

      return SlideTransition(
        position: animation.drive(tween),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Page 2'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```